# I accidentally deleted the admin role from openstack, how can I fix this?

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon

I was trying to remove the role from a user who wasn't supposed to have admin rights, and accidentally removed the role entirely.  Now no user has any permissions through the web GUI or the CLI.  How can I recreate the admin role?

Answer (score 0):

**From the `controller` node**:

Login to the `controller` node and source the `adminrc` file. use `openstack` CLI to re-create the `admin` role.

```
$ openstack role create admin
```

Assign the role to respective user by:

```
$ openstack role add --project <project_name> --user <username> admin
```

If your setup is **DevStack** setup, then login to `devstack` node and execute the steps mentioned above.

Comment: We ended up doing that and created a role called admin which could access the admin tab in the Web GUI.  Unfortunately we were unable to actually access any project details, as it seems that the compute cluster was not responding to any requests.  We've decided to simply reinstall Openstack from scratch.